# Splitting 32 bit register in variable size bytes

Tags: c, embedded, bit

I want to split a  general purpose register into three separate registers; two 8 bit registers & one 16 bit register. This is the approach I am using but I think  it may be wrong.

```
typedef struct {
       volatile uint8_t reg_0;
       volatile uint8_t reg_1;
       volatile uint16_t reg_2;
} reg_split;

#define REG_BASE (0xA040000C)
#define REG ((reg_split *)REG_BASE)
```

And this is how I am accessing the register:

```
REG->reg_0 = 0xFF;
```

Is this the wrong approach or is their a cleaner solution?

Comment: The approach is ok, if your platform's ABI guarantees correct layout. This is platform-dependent anyway. e.g. ARM AAPCS for instance does. However, don't make the single fields `volatile`. Either qualify the `struct`, or the cast.

Comment: Looks like answer was deleted by someone with all the comments. In short is the solution I am currently using sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's most important for all kinds of memory mappings like these, is that you verify that the C code yields the expected result. You have to consider padding and alignment.

Some minor nit-picks with your example:

- Always ensure that all hex literals in your code have a type that makes sense. `0xA040000C` in your case is of a signed type, most likely `unsigned int`. Had you used a literal like `0x5040000C` however, it would be of (signed) `int` type. On most systems it doesn't make sense to have signed addresses. "Sloppy types" can cause all manner of subtle bugs, particularly when combined with various forms of integer promotion.
- Move the volatile qualifier out of the struct. Avoid using type qualifiers inside structs if possible - they usually cause lots of type compatibility hiccups.
- Pointer notation for hardware registers is a bit peculiar. The most common style is to regard registers as declared variables.

With the above remarks in mind, your code could be re-written as:

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t  reg_0;
  uint8_t  reg_1;
  uint16_t reg_2;
} reg_split;

#define REG_BASE (0xA040000Cu)
#define REG (*(volatile reg_split *)REG_BASE)

_Static_assert(sizeof(reg_split) == 4, "Unwanted padding detected");

...

REG.reg_0 = 0xFF;
```

Comment: SIdenote: `0xA040000C` is most likely an unsigned type on platforms with `CHAR_BIT == n * 8` (`n = 1 ..N`). But for clarification and uniformity, it is good practice to make that explicit. And e.g. ARM CMSIS uses pointers for peripheral-register `struct`s. That's just a matter of convention for the platform.